# Spring Boot - Unit Test on Controller - 404 Answer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, junit4, spring-test

I am setting up the unit testing on my @RestController's, but It is not working correctly.

This is only a unit test to validate the answer from the method of the RestEndpoint, but It is not working, please help me because I tried a lot of configurations and read the documentation and nothing worked.

This is my endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clients")
public class ClientsEndpoint extends RestConfiguration {

@Autowired
private IClientService clientService;

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
private Object getById(@PathVariable(required = true) Long id) {
    try {
        Optional<Client> clientOptional = clientService.getById(id);
        if (clientOptional.isPresent()) {
            return clientOptional.get();
        } else 
            return new GeneralResponse(ErrorsEnum.CLIENT_NOT_FOUND);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problemas al obtener datos del cliente con id: " + id, e);
        return new GeneralResponse(ErrorsEnum.GENERAL_ERROR);
    }
}
```

This is my Unit Test where I only added the mock of the endpoint and a simple call is done:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ClientsEndpoint.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ApplicationConfiguration.class})
public class QuarzoApiApplicationTests {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private IClientService clientService;

@Test
public void getById() throws Exception {
    Client client = new Client("Test", "Test", "Test", (byte) 1,
            "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", (byte) 1,
            (byte) 1, (short)1, "Test" );
    Optional<Client> clientOptional = Optional.of(client);
    BDDMockito.given(clientService.getById(anyLong())).willReturn(clientOptional);

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/clients/1")
            .header("Authorization","Bearer " + TestUtils.createToken("miltonc")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Results I am getting after running the unit test:

```
2019-08-27 10:01:18.505  INFO 23606 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7da39774, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5b7c8930, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4277127c, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@441b8382, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1a6dc589, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@40e32762, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6f231ced, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1df1ced0, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2c05ff9d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2a8a4e0c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@27755487]
2019-08-27 10:01:18.526  INFO 23606 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2019-08-27 10:01:18.527  INFO 23606 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2019-08-27 10:01:18.533  INFO 23606 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 6 ms
2019-08-27 10:01:18.555  INFO 23606 --- [           main] i.q.quarzoapi.QuarzoApiApplicationTests  : Started QuarzoApiApplicationTests in 1.371 seconds (JVM running for 1.825)

MOCK org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc@770beef5

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /clients/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NjY5MTQ0NzgsImlzcyI6IlFVQVJaTyIsInN1YiI6Im1pbHRvbmMiLCJleHAiOjE1NjY5NjQ4MDB9.hLu1Mcl_K-8smYnZnDu1ubkVTuNCkQnqhIQuypBsKBzQYxMlYlxqXhsYLCMB5iViCcDK33WXvO1Pjp15TR1ICg"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []



java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
    at io.quarzo.quarzoapi.QuarzoApiApplicationTests.getById(QuarzoApiApplicationTests.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


2019-08-27 10:01:18.772  INFO 23606 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: "Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/login" is your error. Can you please post your full Configuration with class and everything. Your config doesn't seem to get loaded.

Comment: I disabled the CSRF configuration, in the section "My Configuration" I put the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this. I needed to include the @ComponentScan(basePackages = "io.quarzo.api.endpoints") to refer the endpoints I am trying to test.

My Test configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "io.quarzo.api.endpoints")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

After that, I had to Mock every bean I was using in the endpoints.

```
@MockBean(name = "clientRegistrationSingleton")
private Map<String, Client> clientsRegistering;

@MockBean
private IClientService clientService;

@MockBean
private IClientRepository clientRepository;
```

After that all was working ok, I can run the test and mock every Bean to test my @RestController's.

Comment: by using the `@WebMvcTest` you will only load in classes relevant to MVC, and not load in any classes annotated with `@Service` `@RestController` `@Repository` `@Component` etc. thats why you need to mock everything and manually load in your restcontroller annotated classes.

You could instead look into using https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment and then just use `@MockBean` annotation to mock specific beans. Thats more of a standard approach when testing rest apis.